# SQLAlchemy multi column constraint

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a number of tables in different schemas, I used the pattern from the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_tables.html#explicit-schema-name-with-declarative-table).  Some of my tables require multi column constraints and it was unclear what the dictionary key would be for declaring that unique constraint as they mention in the [section above](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_tables.html#declarative-table-configuration)

In my model below, I'd like to create a unique constraint with `name, key, org`. I currently have to do this in sql...

```
class Parent(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'parent'
  __table_args__ = {'schema': 'example'}

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String(512))
  key = Column(String())
  org = Column(String(36))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I encountered that issue a while back. If I remember correctly, it was just a matter of moving the "schema dict" to inside a tuple which also contains your constraints.

I can try to dig further if that does not work, but the documentation seems to agree that using [declarative table configuration](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_tables.html#declarative-table-configuration) via `__table_args__` can be a tuple containing positional arguments (like constraints) and as a final argument a dict with keyword arguments like [schema is for Table](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#schema-table-schema-name).

```py
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('name', 'key', 'org'),
        {'schema': 'example'},
    )

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(512))
    key = Column(String())
    org = Column(String(36))
```

Comment: man i suck at reading docs, after you pointed it out it was right there in the 3rd example... thanks!

Comment: I remember it took me a long time to find a solution when that happened to me. Nowadays I use mostly imperative mappings, which is also worth having a look at to keep models independent.